# Solving $a_{n}a_{n-1}=1,\, a_1=2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, functional-equations

The solution of the recurrence
$$a_{n}+a_{n-1}=1,\, a_1=2$$
is
$$a_n=\frac{1-3(-1)^n}{2}.$$
Could this be somehow used to solve
$$a_{n}a_{n-1}=1,\, a_1=2?$$
Logarithms would turn this to
$$\ln a_n+\ln a_{n-1}=0$$
but that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Calculate the first few terms. It should be clear that$$a_n=\begin{cases}2&n\text{ odd}\\\frac12&n\text{ even}\end{cases}$$

Comment: @lisyarus they don't differ. The question was if you could solve the problem in the title using the solution of another recurrence relation given at the start of the post.

Comment: @snulty indeed, thank you. Shame on me for the rush.

Comment: @lisyarus it's no problem, I had the exact same thought when I first opened the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let

$$b_n:=\frac{3\log_2a_n+1}2$$

and the equation

$$a_na_{n-1}=1$$ can be written

$$b_n+b_{n-1}=1$$ with $b_1=2$.

Hence the solution

$$b_n=\frac{1-3(-1)^n}2$$

or

$$a_n=2^{-(-1)^n}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$a_na_{n-1}=a_{n-1}a_{n-2}\implies a_n=a_{n-2}$$

So, $a_{2m}=\cdots=a_2=a_0$

and $a_{2m+1}=\cdots=?$

Comment: Would this method work for $a_n a_{n-1}a_{n-2}=1,\, a_1=2$ as well? Anyway thanks for your answer.

Comment: @MrPink, $$a_{n-1}a_{n-2}a_{n-3}=1$$ right?

Answer (score 1):

Not that I can see. But if you want to follow through with your first steps, we hope all $a_n$ are greater than $0$.  So $ln(a_n) + ln(a_{n-1}) = 0$ implies
$$ ln(a_n) = ln\left(\frac{1}{a_{n-1}}\right) $$
and so $a_n = 1 / a_{n-1}$.  Given initial condition, you get 
$$ 2,1/2,2,1/2,... $$

Answer (score 0):

Let $$A_n=\frac{k+r^n}{k+r^{n-1}}~~~~(1)$$
Then $$A_n A_{n-1}=1 \implies r=\pm 1. $$
$r=1$ gives trivial result $A_n=1$ which contradicts $A_2=2$.
So from (1), we $k=3$. Hence 
$$A_n=\frac{3+(-1)^n}{3+(-1)^{n-1}}$$